# How to retrieve image from firebase in react native expo?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, expo

I am new to React Native and still learning by doing. I have uploaded images in firebase which I want to show on the second screen. Although, I keep getting errors like

```
can't find variable: profileImageUrl
```

I am trying to retrieve the image on the next page.

Here is the code for uploading to firebase:

```js
const uploadImage = async () => {
  const blob = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function () {
      resolve(xhr.response);
    };
    xhr.oneerror = function () {
      reject(new TypeError('Network request failed'));
    };
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';
    xhr.open('GET', image, true);
    xhr.send(null);
  });

  const ref = firebase.storage().ref().child('/ankit/');

  const snapshot = ref.put(blob);

  snapshot.on(
    firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    () => {
      setUploading(true);
    },

    (error) => {
      setUploading(false);
      console.log(error);
      blob.close();
    },
    () => {
      snapshot.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        setUploading(false);
        console.log('downlaod url', url);
        return url;
      });
    }
  );
};
```

And here is the code for retrieving:

```js
const [Image, setImage] = useState(false);

let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/ankit/');
imageRef
  .getDownloadURL()
  .then((url) => {
    setImage({ profileimageUrl: 'url' });
  })
  .catch((e) => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));

return (
  <View>
    <Image source={this.state.profileImageUrl}></Image>
  </View>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor the code that shows the image. You are using the new hooks state to store the state but try to use it in the `html` with the syntax of the old react state syntax. This is how it should be:

```js
const [image, setImage] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  let imageRef = firebase.storage().ref('/ankit/');
  imageRef
    .getDownloadURL()
    .then((url) => {
      setImage(url);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log('getting downloadURL of image error => ', e));
},[])

return (
  <View>
    <Image src={image}></Image>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Tarik Huber This works without any error, but the new screen comes without any picture. Although I can see it in the firebase.

Comment: Can you pls try to run the updated code. Maybe you just forgot to put it into a `useEffect`

Comment: Got this error: Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `source` supplied to `Image`.

Comment: I think it should be `src`. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you for an answer but got this error "The <Image> component requires a `source` property rather than `src`."

Comment: The `Image` compoenent is a custom one. Where do you get that from?

Comment: The image is imported from react- native:   import { Image, Text, View } from 'react-native';

Comment: const [image, setImage] = useState(false);

Comment: `image` is the state. I mean the `Image` component you are using `<Image/>`

Comment: Or did you want to use the normal `<image/>`?

Comment: Yes, I am using normal <Image/> for react native as it is the component. Can I show image in other way?? I import it from react-native

Comment: Hello @Tarik Huber, Everything is working again. Thank you so much :) It is working in web app!

Comment: Great. It would be nice if you could mark my anser as accepted :)

Comment: Ok! I did it :)